# I work on my first eth smart contract, and I can't deploy it, the error says: "TypeError: XXXXX.deployed is not a function"

Tags: ethereum, solidity, hardhat, erc20

Here is the code for the contract:

```
//contracts/TestToken.sol
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol";


contract TestToken is ERC20Capped {

    address payable public owner;
    constructor(uint256 cap) ERC20("TestToken", "TST") ERC20Capped(cap * (10 ** decimals()))
    {  
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        _mint(owner, 333666999000 * (10 ** decimals()));
    }

    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual override {
        require(ERC20.totalSupply() + amount <= cap(), "ERC20Capped: cap exceeded");
        super._mint(account, amount);
    }

    function destroy() public onlyOwner {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
        _;
    }
}`
```

Here is the deploy.js that gives the error:

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const TestToken = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("TestToken");
  const testToken = await TestToken.deploy(333666999000);

  await testToken.deployed();

  console.log("Test Token deployed: ", testToken.address);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Terminal error: TypeError: testToken.deployed is not a function
at main (C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive\Desktop\ERC 20\test-token\scripts\deploy.js:7:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

```
 Hardhat.config.js:
```

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.17",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: process.env.INFURA_GOERLI_ENDPOINT,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  }
};
```

And here is the error:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO9x6.png)

Sorry guys, might be a silly contract, tried for myself for 3 days now, have little to no experience on Solidity, I'm just trying to learn! Thank you!

(My no-skill guess was that I was missing a package but I searched the whole internet and found only a package about it, the hardhat-ethers one and still, didn't work)

Hardhat Version: 2.17.2

Comment: Share your `hardhat.config.js`, and also version of your `hardhat`

Comment: Also, share the whole error from your terminal.

Comment: I added everything!

Comment: What is your `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` version?

Comment: "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",

Comment: Can you share the command you type to deploy the smart contract?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was a major update to hardhat, try replacing deployed with waitForDeployment()

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating that testToken.deployed is not a function.
You should try to use deployed function on the contract factory. Here is how you can try your code.

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const TestToken = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("TestToken");
  const testToken = await TestToken.deploy(333666999000);

  const deployedTestToken = await TestToken.deployed();

  console.log("Test Token deployed: ", deployedTestToken.address);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```